# How can I get from sql date as date order and date group?

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to the database and I have years in my database;

```
2010
2010
2011
2012
2012
2013
----
```

I want to get year ordered as years and for every year I have to get just one year.

The result must be like this:
2010

```
2010
2011
2012
2013
----
```

Thats my query;

```
@NamedQuery(name = CP.QRY_GET_ALL_COMP_PLAENE_BY_MITARBEITER_ID, query =
            "SELECT c FROM CP.c, Vertrag v " +
                    "WHERE c.vertrag.id = v.id " +
                    "AND c.vertrag.mitarbeiter.id = :" + CP.PARAM_MITARBEITER_ID + " " +
                    "ORDER BY c.jahr DESC ")
```

Comment: Sorry for my english but you could ask before devoting.

Comment: Sorry but with that description nobody will be able to help you, so I am devoting to avoid others waste time trying to understand it. If you change it to something understandble, I can remove the negative vote.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want a jpa solution

Comment: @MertYücel what does "CP.PARAM_MITARBEITER_ID" mean?

Comment: @Grace IT MEANS give workers id as parameter

Comment: @MertYücel what is your query's output?

Comment: @Grace List<CP>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use UNIQUE or DISTINCT keyword, for example,

```
SELECT UNIQUE(YEAR) FROM table_name order by YEAR;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct in your query to get only unique values from your table.

https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_distinct.asp

And looking at the order or your desired result you also want ASC (ascending order) not not DESC (descending order).